# In Moose, if a role defines an attribute with a default, how do I change that default in my consuming class?

Tags: perl, moose, moo

My Moose class consumes a role which I'm not allowed to change. That role defines an attribute with a default. I need my class to have that attribute, but with a different default.

Is that possible?

All I could come up with is surrounding the "new" method with some of my own code, as follows:

```
around new => sub {
    my ($orig, $self) = (shift, shift);
    return $self->$orig(@_, the_attribute => $new_value);
}
```

But I'm not sure if surrounding new is valid, and was also hoping for something more elegant.

Comment: @ikegami: can you make that an answer, and provide an explanation (or link to one) re not overriding new?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A better, simpler way is to write this in your class:

```
has '+the_attribute' => (
    default => sub{1},
}
```

`has` with a `+` lets you override just a specific property of an attribute.

Much simpler than surrounding BUILDARGS.

Answer (score 4):

You have the right idea, but you shouldn't override `new`. [Moose::Manual::BestPractices](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose%3a%3aManual%3a%3aBestPractices) says:

> Never override new
>
> Overriding `new` is a very bad practice. Instead, you should use a `BUILD` or `BUILDARGS` methods to do the same thing. When you override `new`, Moose can no longer inline a constructor when your class is immutabilized.

It's been a while since I've done this, but I think the following will do the trick:

```
around BUILDARGS => sub {
   my $orig  = shift;
   my $class = shift;
   return $self->$orig(
      the_attribute => $new_value,
      @_ == 1 ? %{ $_[0] } : @_,
   );
};
```

Notes:

- I placed the new attribute first to allow it to be overridden.
- I made it so both `->new({ ... })` and `->new(...)` still work. You could use `@_` instead of `@_ == 1 ? %{ $_[0] } : @_` if you don't care about breaking `->new({ ... })`.